# Is there a Quasar equivalent to Semantic UI's pointing label?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, semantic-ui, quasar

I tried using the span pointing property `<span class="label pointing-up bg-primary text-white">up</span>` and QChip's pointing property as explained in the docs, but the pointing part doesn't work. I tried it in different projects, but the property doesn't work. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quasar tooltip component I think.
Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/talksick7/pen/abGqrqr?editors=101) and see if it is any helpful to you.

```js
const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      showing: true
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.7.7/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.7.7/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div
      style="width: 200px; height: 70px;"
      class="bg-purple text-white rounded-borders row flex-center q-mt-md"
    >
      Hover here or click buttons
      <q-tooltip v-model="showing">Tooltip text</q-tooltip>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```